# ESP8266 ESPAsyncWebServer LittleFS crashes

Tags: esp8266, web-server, espressif, esp8266webserver

I am trying to write a simple web page to be served from my ESP8266 based on this tutorial: https://www.mischianti.org/2020/10/26/web-server-with-esp8266-and-esp32-byte-array-gzipped-pages-and-spiffs-2/

However I got a warning saying:

> SPIFFS has been deprecated. Please consider moving to LittleFS or other filesystems.

So I thought I would try using LittleFS as a drop in replacement for SPIFFS, it seemed to be working fine but noticed issues with larger files straight away, the ESP8266 would crash frequently but not consistently, however image files even of smaller sizes would fail to load. Anyway I switched back to SPIFFS and everything seems to work fine as the tutorial suggested it would, can anyone tell me what issue with LittleFS I might be experiencing and if it can be fixed?

Also is it bad practice to use SPIFFS even though it seems to work fine?

Thanks

Comment: I still use SPIFFS, it works and there's nothing "wrong" with it, especially if you have a lots of little (<4kb) files or you want code that runs on the 8266 and 32 both. If you have large files, littleFS is about 5x faster to read and write. If you're directly shipping the whole file over wifi, the wifi part is going to be slower than either filesystem's access.